# Will stackoverflow chat send me notifications and do I need to subscribe?

Tags: support, chat

I haven't spent much time in chat, and sometimes its inactive for a day or so. Is there any mechanism in place to tell me if there are updates?

If so, where should I be looking?

Do I have to "subscribe" first? (If I've created the room, am I subscribed already?)

Comment: Do you want general updates of activity in the chat room, or do you care only about when people mention you specifically by name?

Comment: @CodyGray For the moment, general updates. Do chat notifications work similarly to comments with the `@username` expression (i.e. require it)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each chat room has its own RSS feed, linked on top of the star board:

> [image]

Other than that no way to "subscribe" to a chat room as far as I know. Comments mentioning you i.e. `@joz` would become ordinary notification item after a while (think 10-15 minutes) if you don't enter the room and respond or clear them:

> [image]

Comment: The RSS feed you point out appears to be just a feed of new starred messages, not a feed of all new postings.  The URL for it is `https://chat.stackexchange.com/feeds/rooms/starred/<room-id>`  Is there also a more general feed for the room?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller not that I know of, sorry.